# how to have a nested array with grouping javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a base array like below.

```
const arr1 = [
{id:'1',city:'Sydney',distance:100,yearhalf:'2022_1'},
{id:'2',city:'Melbourne',distance:70,yearhalf:'2022_1'},
{id:'3',city:'Perth',distance:65,yearhalf:'2022_1'},
{id:'4',city:'Sydney',distance:89,yearhalf:'2022_2'},
{id:'5',city:'Melbourne',distance:40,yearhalf:'2022_2'},
{id:'6',city:'Perth',distance:40,yearhalf:'2022_2'}
]
```

The idea is to group the array elements by "yearhalf".I can achieve that with below approach.

```
const groupedArray = arr1((acc,item)=>{
        const itemIndex = acc.findIndex(i=>i.yearhalf === item.yearhalf);

        if(itemIndex !== -1){
            acc[itemIndex][item.city]=[item.distance]
        }
        else{
          acc.push({
             [item.city]:[item.distance],
             yearhalf:item.yearhalf
          })
        }
        return acc;
      },[])
```

The result array will be like below. **Currently at this level.**

```
[
{yearhalf:'2022_1',Sydney:[100],Melbourne:[70],Perth:[65]},
{yearhalf:'2022_2',Sydney:[89],Melbourne:[40],Perth:[40]},
]
```

What I want to do is, **if there are multiple occurrences of same "city" and same "yearhalf" combinations(with different id field of course), push only those distances to existing results**. So having additional entries like below in the initial array(arr1) would change the above result.

```
{id:'7',city:'Sydney',distance:50,yearhalf:'2022_1'},
{id:'8',city:'Melbourne',distance:40,yearhalf:'2022_1'}
```

Since we already have a yearhalf named '2022_1' it should add the city distance to the already existing cityname(Sydney/Melbourne etc) array like below

```
[
{yearhalf:'2022_1',Sydney:[100,50],Melbourne:[70,40],Perth:[65]},
{yearhalf:'2022_2',Sydney:[89],Melbourne:[40],Perth:[40]},
]
```

**Note**: The city name will always be one of Sydney/Melbourne/Perth. Year halves can be have more instances(YYYY_1,YYYY_2) but since initially grouping by them shouldn't cause much of a problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the array and assign if necessary.

```js
const
    arr1 = [{ id: '1', city: 'Sydney', distance: 100, yearhalf: '2022_1' }, { id: '2',city: 'Melbourne', distance: 70, yearhalf: '2022_1' }, { id: '3', city: 'Perth', distance: 65, yearhalf: '2022_1' }, { id: '4', city: 'Sydney', distance: 89, yearhalf: '2022_2' }, { id: '5', city: 'Melbourne', distance: 40,yearhalf: '2022_2' },  { id: '6', city: 'Perth', distance: 40, yearhalf: '2022_2' }, { id: '7', city: 'Sydney', distance: 50, yearhalf: '2022_1' }, { id: '8', city: 'Melbourne', distance: 40, yearhalf: '2022_1' }],
    groupedArray = arr1.reduce((acc, { city, distance, yearhalf }) => {
        const itemIndex = acc.findIndex(i => i.yearhalf === yearhalf);
        if (itemIndex === -1) {
            acc.push({ yearhalf, [city]: [distance] });
        } else {
            (acc[itemIndex][city] ??= []).push(distance);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(groupedArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An approach without searching.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: '1', city: 'Sydney', distance: 100, yearhalf: '2022_1' }, { id: '2',city: 'Melbourne', distance: 70, yearhalf: '2022_1' }, { id: '3', city: 'Perth', distance: 65, yearhalf: '2022_1' }, { id: '4', city: 'Sydney', distance: 89, yearhalf: '2022_2' }, { id: '5', city: 'Melbourne', distance: 40,yearhalf: '2022_2' },  { id: '6', city: 'Perth', distance: 40, yearhalf: '2022_2' }, { id: '7', city: 'Sydney', distance: 50, yearhalf: '2022_1' }, { id: '8', city: 'Melbourne', distance: 40, yearhalf: '2022_1' }],
    grouped = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { city, distance, yearhalf }) => {
        acc[yearhalf] ??= { yearhalf };
        (acc[yearhalf][city] ??= []).push(distance);
        return acc;
    }, []));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It works fine on javascript on the web. But the Nullish Coalescing Operator gives an error on node v14.18.1. I found out it is supported from v15.14.0 onwards. Is there an easy alternative to ??= or should I update node?

Comment: you could replace with logical OR, like for this `acc[itemIndex][city] ??= []` take `acc[itemIndex][city] = acc[itemIndex][city] || []`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the multi-method approach and clarifying the issue with Nullish Coalescing Operator.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
{id:'1',city:'Sydney',distance:100,yearhalf:'2022_1'},
{id:'2',city:'Melbourne',distance:70,yearhalf:'2022_1'},
{id:'3',city:'Perth',distance:65,yearhalf:'2022_1'},
{id:'4',city:'Sydney',distance:89,yearhalf:'2022_2'},
{id:'5',city:'Melbourne',distance:40,yearhalf:'2022_2'},
{id:'6',city:'Perth',distance:40,yearhalf:'2022_2'},
{id:'7',city:'Sydney',distance:50,yearhalf:'2022_1'},
{id:'8',city:'Melbourne',distance:40,yearhalf:'2022_1'}
]

console.log(Object.values(data.reduce((a,
  {city,distance,yearhalf})=>(((a[yearhalf]??={yearhalf})[city]??=[])
  .push(distance)
,a),{})))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.It works on web quite fine but I'm getting an error with "Unexpected token '||='" for the Logical OR assignment. Should be okay after updating to Node 15.x. from 14.18 where I'm currently at.

Comment: @SKR123 it's possible to rewrite `a[b]||=[]` as `a[b]=a[b]||[]`, but it detracts from readability, so it's good to upgrade if you can. I also find it hard to read `]||=` so `??=` is even better